# Use lodash to find parent of granchildren

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, loops, lodash

This is array that I am getting from back end with all checkboxes as selected:

```js
var array = [{
  "name": "Program",
  "children": [{
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Civil Rights",
    "children": [{
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "CNP",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "SNAP",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "WIC",
      "children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "FD",
    "children": [{
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "CSFP",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "FDPIR",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "NSLP",
      "children": []
    }, {
      "isSelected": true,
      "name": "TEFAP",
      "children": []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

What I need to do is when I click on last child to go one above and to change `isSelected` to *true/false* in case of what is selected for child. More depth than this is not possible. Is there some lodash function that can do this? I implemented logic for when checkbox have child to select or deselect all children.

```js
function changeValue(data) {
  if (data.children.length > 0) {
    angular.forEach(data.children, function(children) {
      if (data.isSelected) {
        children.isSelected = true;
      } else {
        children.isSelected = false;
      }
    })
  } else {
    //logic for lat children
  }
}
```

**UPDATE WITH PARENT**

```
     function changeValue (data, parent) {


    if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
        angular.forEach(data.children, function (children) {
            if (data.isSelected) {
                children.isSelected = true;
            }
            else {
                children.isSelected = false;
            }
            if(children.children && children.children.length > 0) {
                changeValue(children);
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        var topParent = parent.$parent.$parent.$parent;
        if (data.isSelected) {
            parent.data.isSelected = true;
            if (topParent.data.name === 'Regions' || topParent.data.name === 'State/Territory') {
                topParent.data.isSelected = true;
            }
            angular.forEach(parent.data.children, function (child) {
               if (!child.isSelected) {
                   parent.data.isSelected = false;
                   if (topParent.data.name === 'Regions' || topParent.data.name === 'State/Territory') {
                       topParent.data.isSelected = false;
                   }
               }
            });
        }
        else {
            parent.data.isSelected = false;
            if (topParent.data.name === 'Regions') {
                topParent.data.isSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PLUNKER**

https://plnkr.co/edit/CKZ9DeHee4pk7GUjVim2?p=preview

Comment: do you want to go top or just one above as you unselect childern all of its parentbecome unselected as well?

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz well in my case only one above will do the job. When I deselect one child need to unselect parent as well. When i select child need to loop trough all children to see if rest of them are selected and then select parent if that is the case.

Comment: So if I get it right, you have some kind of tree structure and when you change status of one of nodes you change status of it's parent node.

Comment: Correct!! I found one good directive for this but I need solution without directive.

Comment: I believe you are using nested ng-repeat for this task so on ng-click instead of sending child just send parent and child as parameter so you could actually edit parent at that time. If you share you html template I could take a closer look,,,

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz updated my question!

Comment: I am afraid I cannot send parent... or if I am wrong can you tell me how I can do that? Cause it will help me a lot...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz I saw that I can send on view parent as $parent.$parent.$parent. Can you take a look how I can change TOP parent node when change some child? Updated my code with parent.

Comment: @Bukic I think the easier way to do this would be to add a reference to the parent on each children. For example, the object with name `"CNP"` would have a prop called `parent` with value `"Civil Rights"`

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz well adding $parent.$parent.$parent will actually give me parent node when click on child checkbox.. I mess up with logic for recursive up and down...